# what is redux in reactjs? and how to quickly adopt this react redux?

Tags: reactjs

recently I got to know about this redux in reactjs. how could we begin with redux?

Comment: redux was created to manage the data of your application. You can think of it as a js object that will contains the useful data to your application (i.e. a list of products, the user information), with redux you can subscribe to and update these data from your components. Try to look at the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Redux basically a state management container like you store your whole application state  init and call when you need it anywhere in your application.

Basically the phenomena is that  you want to send data from one screen to other using props . But what if your application contains 20 pages and numbers of state how you can manage to send state to other If needed. So redux is use to store states and when you call in anywhere  in your application it's easy.